# Using CDN with ember-cli

Tags: cdn, ember-cli

In my app, developed using ember-cli, I need also some external resources like bootstrap;
now I'm importing it through the Brocfile:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
```

Is it possible to use a CDN instead of local file, defining also a callback to local file in case the CDN is offline?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is much benefit to doing this since all your assets will be combined an minified by ember-cli as part of its [asset compilation](http://www.ember-cli.com/#asset-compilation).  What benefit are you trying to get here?

Comment: Well, I use to believe that using CDNs is good practice expecially for largerly used libraries, because many websites use them and so many users already have them in their browser's cache; but it is also a good practice to define a callback, even if CDNs are strong; I do this from my first web app, after reading a document about best practices

Comment: You could just include the script tags to the CDN in `index.html` I  suppose

Comment: Yes, that works, you are right; I was just interested in a way to define a callback to a local copy, just in case... Even if CDNs are strong, it could happen that this will become useful

Comment: What would be interesting for me is how to use the CDN only for production, since for development is faster if you just load the resources locally. Not sure if is possible.

Comment: @JoséLuis: yes what you need is possible: take a look at official documentation, at this paragraph: http://www.ember-cli.com/#environment-specific-assets

Comment: @cereal-killer Not really the solution I'm looking for, you can change between ember.js and ember.prod.js, but in both cases the files are concatenated in the vendor.js file. It is not possible to use vendor.js in development and use a CDN like `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.8.1/ember.prod.js` in production, skipping vendor.js only in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ember-cli-cdn](https://github.com/dakal-oleksandr/ember-cli-cdn) sounds like a partial solution to the problem to me. Here is a quote from the Readme:

> This addon allows to work with local copies of libraries during development, and then automate switching to your CDN version when you deploy your application.

But it doesn't solve the "fallback to local file if CDN is offline" problem. The only pattern I am aware of (also used in ember) is to put the script loading at the end of the html allowing page rendering even if the CDN isn't responding.

Comment: It looks like it now has the fallback (if it didn't when you posted this answer originally), based on the example result on [this page](https://github.com/dakal-oleksandr/ember-cli-cdn). In that example, after the CDN load of jQuery, it has this: `<script>if(!(window.jQuery)) cdnizerLoad("assets/jquery-7decc060e1d33ab4c0ea42ed03d3d797.js");</script>` which will fall back to a local file.