# Ember CLI deps from CDN?

Tags: ember.js, cdn, ember-cli

Loading my ember CLI app currently involved downloading a 3Mb file, most of which consists of common libraries such as jquery, ember, bootstrap, etc.  3Mb is not huge, but it becomes noticable over a slow connection so I want to strip out all the common libraries and get them from a CDN instead.  The idea is that they would be cached by the browser to that they don't need to be re-downloaded every time I update my app (which is very often at the moment).  I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187268/using-cdn-with-ember-cli) question, which points out that it is easy to simply add a `<script...>` to index.html, but I can't figure out how to them tell ember not to package those libraries into vendor.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `brocfile.js` (`ember-cli-build.js` in newer versions) change the constructor to

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  vendorFiles: {
    'jquery.js': false,
    'handlebars.js': false,
    'ember.js': false
  }
});
```

Now include those in your index.html the old fashion way and enjoy the fact that pretty much every users browser already has jquery cached even if they haven't visited your site before.

Answer (score -2):

This is something you get by default with ember-cli.  [From the manual](http://www.ember-cli.com/#asset-compilation):

> When the environment is production (e.g. `ember build --environment=production`), the addon will automatically fingerprint your js, css, png, jpg, and gif assets by appending an md5 checksum to the end of their filename (e.g. `assets/yourapp-9c2cbd818d09a4a742406c6cb8219b3b.js`). In addition, your html, js, and css files will be re-written to include the new name.

You can then modify your `Brocfile.js` to tell it what the base url for your cdn is:

> `prepend` - Default: `''` - A string to prepend to all of the assets. Useful for CDN urls like `https://subdomain.cloudfront.net/`

Comment: whats the advantage with the fingerprint in relation to CDN?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper fingerprinting saves you the headache of cached files on the CDN

Comment: What's the best way to deploy an ember app to some cdb?